# Unity3d facebook SDK and Playhaven

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, playhaven

Having issue with integrating unity facebook and playhaven in my project. everything build fine for android project but after running on phone game crashes.
logcat message

E/AndroidRuntime(11225): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.playhaven.android.view.PlayHavenView

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly what the problem is without the full stack, but this is most likely unrelated to the SDK.

try here: 
[android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragemnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650686/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-6-error-inflating-class-fr)

or google the inflate exception. If you're still stuck, post more info and maybe we can figure this out together.

Thanks for using the SDK!